# Метод из другого класса

Tags: xcode, методы

Как вызвать метод описанный в другом классе?

Comment: А что именно не получается? Я же надеюсь в учебник заглядывали?

Comment: Да уже сколько не гуглил ничего не могу найти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот есть у тебя методы, объявленные в интерфейсе класса:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject

- (void)someMethod;
- (void)someMethodWithParam:(id)param;

@end
```

вот где-то там мы их вызываем, сначала создаем объект этого класса:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    SomeClass *object = [[SomeClass alloc] init]; /* вот тут мы, кстати, тоже вызываем методы, метод класса alloc и метод объекта init */
    // теперь дергаем свои методы
   [object someMethod];
   [object someMethodWithParam:nil];
}
```